# Calculos en un datagridview

Tags: c#, datagrid

Quiero realizar una tabla con un datagridview para ingresar con textbox datos por ejemplo una columna que sea de prestamo otra de interes otra de pago a la semana y la ultima el total 
En el total va el resultado de la operacion de (prestamo * interes) + prestamo - pegosemanal = TOTAL

Entonces Quiero que el data grid se me llene hasta que el TOTAL me de como resultado 0

Codigo de btnCalcular

```
        //Nuevos renglones
         int nuevo = dgvTablaCalculo.Rows.Add();

        decimal prestamo = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrestamo.Text);


            int interes = Convert.ToInt32(txtInteres.Text);
            decimal dinteres = (decimal)interes / 100;

            decimal pagoSemanal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPagoSemanal.Text);
            decimal total = (prestamo * dinteres) + prestamo - pagoSemanal;


            dgvTablaCalculo.Rows[nuevo].Cells[0].Value = prestamo;
            dgvTablaCalculo.Rows[nuevo].Cells[1].Value = interes;
            dgvTablaCalculo.Rows[nuevo].Cells[2].Value = pagoSemanal;
            dgvTablaCalculo.Rows[nuevo].Cells[3].Value = total;

        //total = (prestamo * interes) + prestamo - pagoSemanal;


        txtPrestamo.Text = "";
        txtInteres.Text = "";
        txtPagoSemanal.Text = "";
```

Comment: Cómo estás armando tu lógica? Puedes mostrarnos algo de código para poder ayudarte? Date una vuelta por este link, te servirá mucho: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: El codigo es el siguiente

Comment: Quiero que es datagrid sea como un tipo excel y que se pueda modificar la celda de pagoSemanal y a su vez se vaya haciendo el calculo